# Banner has gaps on either side

Tags: css

so I am trying to make my banner `expand` across the page, 
I have already tried `width: 100%` but it has a gap (about 5px width) on either side, any ideas why it's doing this?

CSS

```
.banner {
width: 100%;
height: 300px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML in your question. This can most likely be fixed with `body { margin: 0; padding: 0}`

Answer (score 3):

It is your browser default margins and padding, do this in your css:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sydluce, it worked a treat!

Comment: No problem! I was happy to help!